# Bootstrap modal inside the repeater ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, repeater

I am trying to show the information in a modal from a repeater. My sample code is fllowing.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptData_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead class="bg-secondary text-info">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Type of Membership</th>
                                    
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="memberNameList" 
                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#memberDetailsModal" runat="server"></button></td>
                                    <td><asp:Literal id="typeOfMembershipList" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
                                    
                                </tr>
                                <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="form-title text-center">
                                                    <h3 class="font-weight-bold" id="memberName" runat="server">Member Name</h3>
                                                   <p class="font-weight-bold mb-0" id="typeOfMembership" runat="server">General Member</p>
                                                </div>
                                               
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                            </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I can get all the data from the database in the table in multiple rows. But when I click the button from any row to pop up the modal, it's showing the information from the first row only in the modal. I am getting that, the modal is binding only the information from the first row. I am not sure why.

Comment: Why would you put a modal inside a Repeater? And what do you think will happen with the Modal's ID `id="memberDetailsModal`?

Comment: I actually didn't use the id of the modal anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same modal for every row. Pass the values using HTML data-* attributes to the modal and then, you can use jQuery to get the data and modify the modal dynamically.

[Bootstrap Docs: Varying modal content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)